Space of conics tangent to a given line
We work over the complex numbers. I know that the space of conics is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^5$, by mapping the entries $a_{i,j}$, $i\geq j$, of the symmetric matrix defining a conic.
I would like to prove the following statement:
Claim: Let $L$ be a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$, and let $D$ be the set of conics whose tangent line is $L$. Then $D$ is a divisor in $\mathbb{P}^5$.
While intuitively I see (tangency is one condition, so the space will have dimension 4) why this holds, I would like to have a computation proof.
Namely let $C$ denote both the conic given by the zero locus of $$F: ax^2+bxy+cxz+dy^2+eyz+fz^2$$in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and the associated matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
b & d & e\\
c & e & f
\end{pmatrix}
Let $L$ be for instance the line $z=0$. The tangent line of $C$ at a point $p$ will be
$$\tau: F_x(p) x+F_y(p) y+F_z(p)z=0,$$
If I want $\tau$ to be equal to $L$, I have a system
\begin{cases}
2a+b+c=0 \\
b+2d+e=0
\end{cases}
But now this system does not show that $D$ is a divisor, so I am a bit confused.

A quick way to do this is to plug the equation of the line in to the equation of the conic and ensure there is only a single point of intersection. In your example, this would give you that $ax^2+bxy+dy^2=0$ should cut out a single point in the $\Bbb P^1$ which is $V(z)\subset\Bbb P^2$, which is equivalent to $b^2-4ad=0$. This determines a divisor on the space of conics.

Your mistake lies in your computation of the coefficients of the tangent line to the conic at $p$. These should depend on $p$, yours don't. In fact, at $p=(p_x,p_y,p_z)$ the tangent line is cut out by $$(2ap_x+bp_y+cp_z)x+(bp_x+2dp_y+ep_z)y+(cp_x+ep_y+2fp_z)z=0.$$
To see when this is equal to the line $z=0$, we need to tell when $2ap_x+bp_y+cp_z$ and $bp_x+2dp_y+ep_z$ vanish. But this system of linear equations can be rewritten as $$\begin{pmatrix} 2a & b & c \\ b & 2d & e \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p_x \\ p_y \\ p_z\end{pmatrix}=0,$$ so the condition is there exists a point $p$ on $L$ and the conic so that this system is solvable. Saying the point $p$ is on $L$ means $p_z=0$, so we're down to $$\begin{pmatrix} 2a & b \\ b & 2d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p_x \\ p_y\end{pmatrix}=0,$$ which only has nontrivial solutions if the determinant of the left matrix is zero. This determinant is $4ad-b^2$, which is exactly what we saw up at the top.
